# How to count unique visitors on webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I want to know how to count unique visitors on webpage with Javascript (ReactJS + NodeJS(Express) i mean when user loads page it should send user's data to validate and if it is unique add it to database. there are this options (what i figured out)

1. Use client's IP address as validator.
2. Set Cookie

first one is not good because many device can share same network and many visitors will be lost.

Second one is not good option because cookie can be manipulated & deleted (if it is httpOnly then only deleted)

So what is best way to count visitors? my aim is to make something like [image]. this

Comment: Have you considered using an analytic platform, like google analytics or matomo ?

Comment: There are many analytics platforms that use complex methods to identify returning visitors. And as well as many ways to circumvent them: block cookies, block js, block canvases, ... Just count the number of times a page loads

Comment: can i display it's result on webpage?

Comment: @niklas if i "Just count the number of times a page loads"  any person will be able to increase views quantity and  in that case it will not worth at all

Comment: Here you don't count multiple tab loads as a unique visit? If you do this from scratch generate a unique key on each visit and store that in there browser local storage match the value with server and insert the visit as unique.

Comment: local storage can be deleted and manipulated also

Comment: At the end of the day, you have to rely on the clients' machine - something out of your control. Cookies and/or local storage is the best you are going to get

Answer (score 1):

You can add a field in your database schema in which you can update it by adding 1 or something similar when a user visits a page. If you want to go further you can then store the user IP in the database or use cookies to avoid counting page visits for the same person multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. Google Analytics and their core reporting API. After you included GA in your site, the [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) will get you started.